# Google Admob is not crawling app-ads.txt file

Tags: admob, google-play-services, adsense, google-crawlers, app-ads.txt

Google Admob is not crawling app-ads.txt file

My app is on playstore, I have placed the ad, and put up the app-ads.txt file as well.
https://plotperty.com/app-ads.txt

Why it is not crawling it?

I have tried to work with 4 developers on this issue. But google does not even crawl to give any error or approval, it just stays blank